# Coding Zones for Android Maps

Tags: android, mapping

How would you go about designing a system based on arbritary zones? Think of the American states - basically the whole map is carved up into irregular zones. Then again another one might show a salesmans territory, TV stations coverage area etc. I need to be able to retrieve the current GPS position and determine which zone I'm in. I can't use an address/zip lookup - its purely based on the lat/long point. So the data structures which define the enclosing boundaries must be flexible enough to provide fairly accurate positioning. As a bonus, I'd also like to be able to render these zones on the map, maybe with different colors. Any tips/pointers to anything close to this would be very welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your zones are just polygons. I would start here:

- [Google maps point in polygon](http://dawsdesign.com/drupal/google_maps_point_in_polygon)
- [Point in polygon strategies](http://erich.realtimerendering.com/ptinpoly/)
- [Check if a polygon contains a coordinate in Google Maps](http://dawsdesign.com/drupal/google_maps_point_in_polygon)
- [Wikipedia Point in polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)